# Можно ли в css добавить значение margin-top к текущему?

Tags: css

Можно ли в css добавить значение margin-top к текущему, если да то как?

есть ли синтаксис что то вроде:

```
margin-top: += 100px;
```

Я хочу сделать небольшой плавный спуск текста на странице при её загрузке

Comment: Подобного синтаксиса нет в css. Что конкретно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Я хочу сделать небольшой плавный спуск текста на странице при загрузке

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.